# Any video opened in VLC comes on top of other windows and drop down even when vlc is minimised

Tags: unity, video, vlc, video-player

I am using Unity desktop. This issue is not particular to `vlc`. Happens same with `kmplayer` and `mplayer` too, but not with default video player.

Screenshot below. (VLC is minimized but then too video takes over the terminal).

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue gets fixed by running vlc using command

```
vlc --no-overlay
```